# оишбка Getting unknown property: app\models\FunctionParameter::parameter_type

Tags: php, yii2, yii

в моделе FunctionParameter.php

```
public function getParameterType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ParameterType::className(), ['id' => 'parameter_type_id']);
}
```

в моделе ParameterType.php

```
public function getFunctionParameters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FunctionParameter::className(), ['parameter_type_id' => 'id']);
}
```

все сгенеривано через gii.
в базе была ошибка в названии столбца. исправил название столбца через воркбенч, перегенировал модели и стала появляться ошибка.

Comment: Добрый день. Значит ошиблись в написании имени. Или же очистите директорию runtime/cache.

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Где-то в коде осталось `parameter_type`, в то время как для получения связанной модели нужно использовать `parameterType`